# Animate colors of a Div using jquery color plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to change to color of a Div element on my page, using Jquery and Jquery color plugin. Can you please explain what am I doing wrong here? I'm trying to change to colors to red, yellow,lime and blue...

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>  
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/color/jquery.color.plus-names-2.1.2.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("button").click(function () {
            var div = $("div");         
            div.animate({ height: '300px', opacity: '0.4',color:'red' }, 1000);
            div.animate({ width: '300px', opacity: '0.8',color:'yellow' }, 1200);
            div.animate({ height: '100px', opacity: '0.4',color:'lime' }, 1230);
            div.animate({ width: '100px', opacity: '0.8',color:'blue' }, 1234);
        });
    });
</script> 
</head>

<body>
<button>Start Animation</button>
<div style="background:#123456;height:100px;width:100px;position:absolute;">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `color` refers to text color. Use `backgroundColor` to change the color of the background.

Comment: Thank you so much! I can't belive how I did this mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The css property [`color`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_color.asp) sets the color for text, not background color. The css property for that is [`background-color`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-color.asp).

However, jQuery expects css properties without dashes and in [lower camel case](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?LowerCamelCase). So in jQuery you would reference it as `backgroundColor`:

```
div.animate({ height: '300px', opacity: '0.4', backgroundColor:'red' }, 1000);
```